# addEventListner , keypress event not working

Tags: javascript, html

Hi im trying to make is so that when you press enter while the focus is on input in javascript

**However** its not working but giving me this message:

> X script.js:163 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

This is the input:

```html
<input type="search" id="in1" class="form-control">
```

> **Note:** I' using bootstrap

This is the code i tried:

```js
document.getElementById("in1").addEventListener("keypress",callSearchDB);
```

This is the `callSearchDB()` function:

```js
function callSearchDB(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Why its not working

Comment: The element you are trying to find is not in the DOM when the function is executed. Maybe you placed the script at the beginning of the html

Comment: You have 3 options. a) add a `defer` attribute to the `<script>` tag. b) put the script tag after the element it references. c) warp the function in `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { ... })`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event) so you can be sure that your HTML document is completely parsed before your JavaScript runs.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.getElementById("in1").addEventListener("keypress", callSearchDB);
});


function callSearchDB(e) {
  if (e.keycode === 13 || e.key === 'Enter') {
    console.log('entered')
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="search" id="in1" class="form-control">
```